# Proving theorems about functions with cases

Tags: idris

Let's say we have a function `merge` that, well, just merges two lists:

```
Order : Type -> Type
Order a = a -> a -> Bool

merge : (f : Order a) -> (xs : List a) -> (ys : List a) -> List a
merge f xs [] = xs
merge f [] ys = ys
merge f (x :: xs) (y :: ys) = case x `f` y of
                                   True  => x :: merge f xs (y :: ys)
                                   False => y :: merge f (x :: xs) ys
```

and we'd like to prove something clever about it, for instance, that merging two non-empty lists produces a non-empty list:

```
mergePreservesNonEmpty : (f : Order a) ->
                         (xs : List a) -> (ys : List a) ->
                         {auto xsok : NonEmpty xs} -> {auto ysok : NonEmpty ys} ->
                         NonEmpty (merge f xs ys)
mergePreservesNonEmpty f (x :: xs) (y :: ys) = ?wut
```

Inspecting the type of the hole `wut` gives us

```
wut : NonEmpty (case f x y of   True => x :: merge f xs (y :: ys) False => y :: merge f (x :: xs) ys)
```

Makes sense so far! So let's proceed and case-split as this type suggests:

```
mergePreservesNonEmpty f (x :: xs) (y :: ys) = case x `f` y of
                                                    True => ?wut_1
                                                    False => ?wut_2
```

It seems reasonable to hope that the types of `wut_1` and `wut_2` would match the corresponding branches of `merge`'s case expression (so `wut_1` would be something like `NonEmpty (x :: merge f xs (y :: ys))`, which can be instantly satisfied), but our hopes fail: the types are the same as for the original `wut`.

Indeed, the only way seems to be to use a `with`-clause:

```
mergePreservesNonEmpty f (x :: xs) (y :: ys) with (x `f` y)
  mergePreservesNonEmpty f (x :: xs) (y :: ys) | True = ?wut_1
  mergePreservesNonEmpty f (x :: xs) (y :: ys) | False = ?wut_2
```

In this case the types would be as expected, but this leads to repeating the function arguments for every `with` branch (and things get worse once `with` gets nested), plus `with` doesn't seem to play nice with implicit arguments (but that's probably worth a question on its own).

So, why doesn't `case` help here, are there any reasons besides purely implementation-wise behind not matching its behaviour with that of `with`, and are there any other ways to write this proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stuff to the left of the `|` is only necessary if the new information somehow propagates backwards to the arguments.

```
mergePreservesNonEmpty : (f : Order a) ->
                         (xs : List a) -> (ys : List a) ->
                         {auto xsok : NonEmpty xs} -> {auto ysok : NonEmpty ys} ->
                         NonEmpty (merge f xs ys)
mergePreservesNonEmpty f (x :: xs) (y :: ys) with (x `f` y)
  | True = IsNonEmpty
  | False = IsNonEmpty

-- for contrast
sym' : (() -> x = y) -> y = x
sym' {x} {y} prf with (prf ())
-- matching against Refl needs x and y to be the same
-- now we need to write out the full form
  sym' {x} {y=x} prf | Refl = Refl
```

As for *why* this is the case, I do believe it's just the implementation, but someone who knows better may dispute that.

Comment: I find this criteria of the information propagating/affecting the arguments a bit vague (like, every `case` affects what we know about the arguments, so what exactly constitutes this?). But, maybe, this is something of more an intuition kind of thing that'd be improved as one writes more Idris code.

Comment: The backwards propagation meant here is the *refining of argument types* due to the type of the pattern in the `with` branch.

Comment: @Cactus I guess I understand well what's "refining" if that gives more precise information about the constructor of the given type. But what is refined in the types in a case like matching over `f x y` as in my original question? Again, doesn't it mean that every `if`/`case` statement refines the types somehow?

Comment: @0xd34df00d Nothing. That’s the point of this answer. Some matches reveal something about the structure of the arguments, at which point you must use the full form. This one doesn’t, so the abbreviation is valid. I don’t know exactly what @Cactus is trying to say about argument types, but the important things are the structure (what expression is equal to?) of the arguments and the type of the pattern. In `sym'`, the `Refl` pattern would not be well typed unless `x` and `y` were identical, so we refine them to make it well typed. A match on `Bool` is always well typed, telling us nothing.

Comment: @HTNW ah, I got to learn to read, somehow completely missed lacking everything to the left of `|` first time. Now I fully get what you meant, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's an issue about proving things with `case`: https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/4001

Because of this, in [idris-bi](https://github.com/sbp/idris-bi) we ultimately had to remove all `case`s in such functions and define separate top-level helpers that match on the case condition, e.g., like [here](https://github.com/sbp/idris-bi/blob/master/src/Data/Bip.idr#L254-L267).

Comment: You don't even need the `foo1` indirection, I get the same behaviour by just case-splitting on `f`. Actually, this is very close to my next question, so I guess I'll ask it too.